# Get value of material UI buttons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I have 2 button with values. I want to run a function when someone clicks them that console logs the value. The problem is that I'm using material UI and when I try to use e.target.value it returns undefined.

I've looked around but only found solutions that update the state onChange but I can't do that because I don't have a textbox.

This is what I've tried to do:

```
 const search = async (e) => {
     console.log(e.target.value)
 }

 <Button value="buttonValue" onClick={search}>Button</Button>
```

The code above works if it's a normal button so the problem is with Material UI. Sorry if this is a basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
 const search = async (e) => {
     console.log(e.currentTarget.value)
 }

 <Button value="buttonValue" onClick={search}>Button</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const search = (value,e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(value)
  }
      
 <Button value="buttonValue" onClick={this.search.bind(this,buttonValue)}>Button</Button>
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

```
  onClick={(e)=>console.log(e.currentTarget.value)}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Use `currentTarget` instead of `target`

```
 const search = (event) => {
        console.log(event.currentTarget.value); //buttonValue
    }

 <Button value="buttonValue" onClick={search}>Button</Button>
```

Code sample:- https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-darkness-gncu0?file=/src/App.js:128-211